# How to pull out the guides from ruler like photoshop in sketch 3?

Tags: sketch-app

[image]

I am learning sketch 3.
I need to create new guides.
Smart guides can't help me in sketch 3.
Is there a way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Double click the ruler to add a guide, they don't behave in the same manor as Photoshop.

Here is the documentation for [Rulers, Guides & Grids in Sketch 3](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/documentation/10-canvas/2-rulers-guides-grids.html), check out the ruler section.

Comment: My sincere thanks for your timely and generous assistance and I hope I can reciprocate some day.

Comment: No problem at all =) That's what the Stack Exchange network is all about. If this answers your question, feel free to mark it as correct for future visitors.

Comment: Never seen a more cordial response @JeSum. Good on you.